# vb.net How to set the long text to next line instead of showing periods(....) in Print Preview data from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I know this could be a minor fixes but I dont know how to fix this code to suit for my needs. I need to show the long text to my print preview into next line for continuation instead of set it to show periods like (.......) when it is not fit to column. how to do that?
This code is from Plutonix. Credits to him. Somebody could help?

```
Private mRow As Integer = 0
Private newpage As Boolean = True

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object,
                    e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    ' sets it to show '...' for long text
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    Dim y As Int32 = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim rc As Rectangle
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim h As Int32 = 0
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow

    ' print the header text for a new page
    '   use a grey bg just like the control
    If newpage Then
        row = dgvZZ.Rows(mRow)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            ' since we are printing the control's view,
            ' skip invidible columns
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                ' reused in the data pront - should be a function
                Select Case dgvZZ.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvZZ.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText,
                                            dgvZZ.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If
        Next
        y += h

    End If
    newpage = False

    ' now print the data for each row
    Dim thisNDX As Int32
    For thisNDX = mRow To dgvZZ.RowCount - 1
        ' no need to try to print the new row
        If dgvZZ.Rows(thisNDX).IsNewRow Then Exit For

        row = dgvZZ.Rows(thisNDX)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        h = 0

        ' reset X for data
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left

        ' print the data
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                ' SAMPLE CODE: How To 
                ' up a RowPrePaint rule
                'If Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells(5).Value) < 9.99 Then
                '    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.MistyRose)
                '        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rc)
                '    End Using
                'End If

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                Select Case dgvZZ.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                      dgvZZ.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If

        Next
        y += h
        ' next row to print
        mRow = thisNDX + 1

        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            ' mRow -= 1   causes last row to rePrint on next page
            newpage = True
            Return
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: The code is meant to print a DGV not a report.  The default text handling in the DGV for long text is to use ellipses (...).  If thats not what you want, resize the columns so they are long enough for the text.

Comment: Ok Sir Plutonix, but it could be possible to make a report from bound datagridview? instead of using Print Preview to print. Do you have any tutorials for vb.net?

Comment: Well Sir Plutonix I found a solution now, Setting the wrap mode of rows to true, and it works.